# How do I filter a result set in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a dinky little web service written in Entity Framework Core that returns a list of coils that have been, are being or will be annealed.  I don't care about the ones that have been annealed. How do I put filter out the finished ones?

The `Inventory` table includes a column `archived`. I want to query for those rows for which the `archived` column contains zero. How do I do that?

The query is being performed in an extension method on the `IEndpointRouteBuilder` interface:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using CAPSWebServer.CapsDataModels;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
{
    public static class CAPSServiceEndpoint
    {
        public static void MapWebService(this IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapGet("caps/coils", async context =>
            {
                CapsDataContext data = context.RequestServices.GetService<CapsDataContext>();
                var coils = data.Inventories;                
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize<IEnumerable<Inventory>>(data.Inventories));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `archived` is a bool, you should be able to do `await data.Inventories.Where(inventory => !inventory.Archived).ToListAsync();`. You'll most likely need a `using` for `System.Linq` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: Silly me.  "using System.Linq" is what I was missing.  Thanks very miuch!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `archived` is a bool, you should be able to do:

`await data.Inventories.Where(inventory => !inventory.Archived).ToListAsync();`.

You'll most likely need a `using` for `System.Linq` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: Silly me.  "using system.Linq" is what I was missing.  Thanks very much!